# jQuery Get the second or x div with certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This should be simple, but I can't figure it out

For example, lets assume the class .contentdiv is what were searching for.

I want to obtain (or select) the second or (x amount) .contentdiv in a document then get the html of that div.

x being the div i want to select so pretend x is 1,2 or 3 or any number

```
jQuery('#slider').filter('.contentdiv').match(x).html();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways, but:

```
$('#slider').filter('contentdiv').eq(x).html();
```

also

```
$('#slider').filter('.contentdiv:eq(' + x + ')').html();
```

but that's messier (in my opinion).

*edit* — thanks @patrick: the initial selector is selecting a single element (of necessity, because "id" values have to be unique).  Perhaps you meant `$('#slider div.contentdiv')` which would get all the `<div>` elements *under*` the "slider" container.

And another good comment further clarifies that the indexing of  `.eq()` and the ":eq()" selector thingy is zero-based.

Comment: `$('#slider')` should return only 1 result, so `.filter()` probably isn't right here.

Comment: Oh right; duhh :-)  I was just blindly copying from the question.  Thanks; I'll update the answer.

Comment: Also, `.eq` indexes from 0. Worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

If `.contentdiv` elements are located inside the `#slider` element then you need `.find()` instead of `.filter()`.

Any of these would work for you:

```
jQuery('#slider').find('.contentdiv').eq(1);
jQuery('#slider .contentdiv').eq(1);
jQuery('#slider .contentdiv:eq(1)');
```

replacing `1` with whatever number (or variable) you want, and ending with `.html()`.

- http://api.jquery.com/find/
- http://api.jquery.com/eq/
- http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Hm..

`$('#slider').find('.contentdiv:eq(x)').html();`

edit...

`$('#slider').find('.contentdiv:eq(' + x + ')').html();`

Comment: If `x` is a variable, then it needs to be concatenated into the string. Right now it will be passing an invalid character. See @Pointy's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `nth-child` selector? For example, `#slider .contentdiv:nth-child(2)`?

Comment: This *might* be right, but it's looking for elements based on position in the DOM, not position in a selected list.